# Invalid syntax when creating lists

Tags: python, list

So i am attempting to create 3 different lists one of 1k, one of 10k, and one of 100k items long populated with random numbers from 1 to 10million but i cant seem to figure out why it keeps saying its invalid syntax. So far i have:

edit: okay it seems to have fixed the invalid syntax problem with some tweaking but still gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/funtime.py", line 16, in <module>
    print (list[1])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

this is exactly what i have typed in:

```
import random

def createlist(a):

    blist =[]
    count=0
    while count <= a:

        blist.append(random.randint(1,10000000))
        count= count+1
    return blist;


list1= createlist(10000);

print (list[1])
```

Comment: what language ? where does it say syntax error ? (which line?)

Comment: Sorry its Python and the syntax error is  on the print line specifically on the "list1"

Comment: can not see how it fails.you may need to paste the exact error message here.maybe due to misspelling of "print"

Comment: Of course that gives you an error, because `list` is a type and your variable's name is list1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some other answers have stated, you could easily use [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) for something like this (the so-called *Pythonic* way):

```
somelist = [random.randint(1, 1000000) for i in xrange(10000)]
```

List comprehension is fast in Python because it is executed by underlying C code. Moreover, using `xrange` is more memory-efficient.

Note: By convention, when the loop-control variable is not used in Python, it is named `_`:

```
somelist = [random.randint(1, 1000000) for _ in xrange(10000)]
```

Comment: So just to make sure this is not limiting the numbers assigned to being only in the 10000 range, but giving the list 10000 items?

Comment: Correct - the resulting list will have 10000 items.

Comment: hmmm the reason i asked is cause it doesnt seem to be outputting any numbers over 999,999

Comment: Also it doesnt seem to recognize xrange when using that.

Comment: Yes 999,999 is the highest number in the range (1, 1000000). Also, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: If xrange is not found, you'll probably have to go with normal range.

Comment: Thank you! If it wasnt obvious im a fairly new programmer and still trying to get the hang of python ( I started in C++). It seems i am unable to count zeroes as well Haha. But thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/funtime.py", line 16, in <module>
    print (list[1])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Objects of type `type` are indeed not subscriptable. `list` is the name of the builtin list class, which is an instance of `type`. It doesn't make any sense to subscript it, so that's clearly not what you intended to do.

You meant `print (list1[1])`. `list1` is the name you bound to your list object created by `createlist(10000)`.

The trick to finding these sort of bugs is to look at the error message Python gave you. It's telling you exactly the problem line, and exactly why it's a problem. All that was missing was the realisation that `list` is not the name of the object you wanted to subscript.

Comment: As near as I can tell, this is the only answer which actually explains what's going on.  (I'm also not sure if the OP knows that Python lists are 0-indexed or if `1` was just a random value.)

Answer (score 2):

The following works fine on my system.

```
import random

def createlist(a):

    blist =[]
    count= 0
    while count <= a:
        blist.append(random.randint(1,1000000))
        count=count+1
    return blist

list1= createlist(10000)

print list1[1]
```

http://ideone.com/SL2bL <-- try it here.

I'd probably do it like this

```
import random

def createlist(a):

    return [random.randint(1,1000000) for i in xrange(a)]


list1= createlist(10000)

print list1[1]
```

Or probably just skip the function..

```
list1 = [random.randint(1,1000000) for i in xrange(a)]
print list1[1]
```

Comment: Exactly correct process, in terms of letting people write correct code in PYTHON

Comment: I think you forgot to delete `count=count+1` in the second portion of code.

Answer (score 2):

A much shorter version would be:

```
>>> import random
>>> def create_list(length):
...     return [random.randint(1,1000000) for _ in range(length)]
```

This demonstrates a couple of things:

1. A much more compact way to loop `x` times (the `for _ in range(length)` idiom)
2. [List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create lists, instead of repeated calls to `append`.
3. The use of `_` as a variable name when you need the variable, but not the actual data in it. This is a somewhat common convention that crops up most often in list comprehensions. It isn't a problem not to use it, but it crops up often enough that it pays to be aware of it.

Hat-tip to @mgilson for his comment on another answer that reminded me the `_` convention.

Comment: there is no such need to write such a function

Comment: I recommend xrange over range here. You don't need it generating a huge list to iterator over.

Comment: @zinking That's true for this case, but there's nothing wrong with the basic idea of a factory function. It's entirely possible that this is a simplified case that cuts out some extraneous extra work that the original function was doing.

Comment: @desimusxvii I thought about that, but the trend has been to move toward using `range`, since `xrange` was refactored into `range` in Python 3, and many library maintainers prefer to support both 2 and 3 out of the same code base. Obviously, if you use this for huge lists, you may want to use `xrange` anyway. I could *swear* there's a way to make `itertools` do the heavy lifting here, but it's late where I am, and my quick scan of the docs didn't show it to me.

Answer (score 1):

use a list comprehension (its way betta and makes you look pro, haha)

```
[random.randint(1, 1000000) for i in range(10000)]
```

Comment: xrange is preferable to range in this case.

Comment: @desimusxvii only if using python2.x -- and based on the parenthesis in `print (list[1])`, OP might not be.

Comment: "C:/Python32/funtime.py" strongly suggests it's 3.2.

Comment: I would change it to `[random.randint(1,1000000) for _ in range(10000)]` since you're not actually using the variable `i`.  (`_` is a common variable name for stuff that you need to make the syntax work, but you don't actually need to use the data)

Comment: @DSM -- *grumbles* always making me look bad by noticing these small details that I completely didn't pick up on ... :^)

Answer (score -1):

First, you don't put a paren by `while` unless you're evaluating complex expressions.

Next, you used a semicolon to return your `blist`. Not necessary.

Finally...why not use a for loop?

```
import random

def createlist(a): 
    blist =[]

    for x in xrange(a):
        blist.append(random.randint(1,1000000))

    return blist

list1= createlist(10000)

print list1[0]
```

Comment: Why would i need to check count and not a? i am merely filling the list with random numbers and that sets the length of the list by counting up to a which is the length im passing to it. I think the better question is why would i use a for loop over a while?

Comment: I wrote that before your edit, when you showed `a` as an argument into the function. As for the `for` loop, you can discard the counter variable you were using, as `for` loops manage their own sentinels.

Comment: 'for' loops are generally for a set number of iterations. While loops generally are waiting for an indeterminate condition.

Comment: It is not invalid syntax to put parenthesis on `while`. Try this: `while (True): print 1`.

Comment: You're right. OP didn't complain about a specific error, I jumped at the first thing my eyes complained about without looking hard enough.